# ImportError with unittest and multiples modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, importerror, directory-structure

I have a project with the following structure:

```
/
├── test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_do_stuff.py
└── my_package
    ├── do_stuff.py
    ├── helpers
    │   ├── my_helper.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── main_do_stuff.py
```

When running the tests I get `ImportError: No module named 'helpers'`

When the test imports `my_package.do_stuff`, it tries to import `helpers.my_helper`

- The command to run the tests is `python3 -m unittest` (Is this a correct way?)
- All the `__init__.py` are empty.

test_do_stuff.py:

```
import unittest
import my_package.do_stuff
# ...
```

do_stuff.py:

```
import helpers.my_helper
# ...
```

main_do_stuff.py:

```
import do_stuff
```

`python3 my_package/main_do_stuff.py` works.
The main calls the same functions as the test.

Does the problem comes from the way I launch the tests?

Or my structure?

I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't involve messing too much with the path or writing a lot of code just to run the tests. (There should be a simple way to have the tests separated from the code doesn't it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of implicit relative imports:

`import helpers.my_helper`

should be

`import my_package.helpers.my_helper`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that python doesn't accept your directory hieracy. Just put the test files under a root directory ( /everything for example ) and it will work fine. Your directorys could look like this:

```
/
└── everything
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── test_do_stuff.py
    └── my_package
        ├── do_stuff.py
        ├── helpers
        │   ├── my_helper.py
        │   └── __init__.py
        ├── __init__.py
        └── main_do_stuff.py
```

Comment: Moving `test_do_stuff.py` and `__init__.py` to the root still gives the same error. Did I forgot something from your proposal?